# Import unique records from datatable to sql table

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, datatable, dataset

I have a datatable matching the structure of a MS Sql table and I would like to import new records from the datatable into SQL.

So, in the example below, I am looking to import the record for Jim.

**DataTable:**

```
Name   DOB        Country
Brian  11-11-78   USA
Dave   01-01-80   UK
Jim    02-02-81   FR
```

**SQL:**

```
Name   DOB        Country
Brian  11-11-78   USA
Dave   01-01-80   UK
```

Comment: What is the primary key on your tables? You can import all the records from the original DB to a temporary table then perform a MERGE (SQL Server)

Comment: Sorry I have no PK. I planned to combine use a combination of Name and DOB to distinguish.

Comment: Also take a look at Microsoft Sync Framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can make an SP, and pass on the values that you have in your DataTable, and use [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) to do INSERT/UPDATE:

Pruned according to your data, assuming the name of your SQL table is `_DOB`:

```
MERGE INTO _DOB AS Target

USING  (--SELECT NAME,DOB,COUNTRY FROM FROM YOUR DataTable
        VALUES ('Jim','1978-11-11', 'FR')
       )
       AS Source (Name, DOB, Country)
ON 
    Target.Name = Source.Name
    AND Target.DOB = Source.DOB

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
        Target.Name = Source.Name,
        Target.DOB = Source.DOB,
        Target.Country = Source.Country

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Name, DOB, Country) 
    VALUES (Source.Name, Source.DOB, Source.Country);
```

Comment: No need for a Stored Procedure, just Bulk Copy the data in to a temp table then use the MERGE statement (as you have shown above) to update the destination. That should be much more efficient than merging each row individually.

Comment: Depending upon the size of data and frequency of operation, it could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up and it seems to do the trick. Thanks all for the input.

```
this.conn = new oleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM name", conn);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(ds, "name");

DataTable data = ds.Tables["name"];

sqlCommand = "CREATE TABLE ##TempTable(Name, DOB, Location)";

SqlConnection SQLconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection1"].ConnectionString);
SQLconn.Open();

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, SQLconn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.ExecuteReader();

    SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    // Map the columns
    foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "##TempTable";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(data);
}

string MergeCommand = string.Concat("insert into [Existing Table] (Name, DOB, Location) ",
    "select distinct Name, DOB, Location from ##TempTable ",
    "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Existing Table] a WHERE a.[Name] = ##TempTable.[Name] and a.[DOB] = ##TempTable.[DOB])");

SqlConnection Mergeconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
Mergeconn.Open();

using (SqlCommand MergeCmd = new SqlCommand(MergeCommand, Mergeconn))
{
    MergeCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    MergeCmd.ExecuteReader();
}

SQLconn.Close();
Mergeconn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO
    datatable (name, dob, country)
SELECT
    name, dob, country
FROM
    sql
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            datatable 
        WHERE
            datatable.name=sql.name AND
            datatable.dob=sql.dob
    )
```